# Error in model.frame.default ... invalid type (list) for variable

Tags: r, neural-network, linear-regression

I'm fairly new to R and I'm trying to create a model to work on Kaggle's Facial Keypoint Detection sample project. The ultimate issue is that creating any model (I'm trying a neural net using the neuralnet project, but I've also tried simpler linear models via lm) won't take the image as a predictor for the model as a list of integers, but I can't seem to get it into a form that the modelling functions will take.

I'm loading the data like so:

```
# load.R

library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

cluster <- makeCluster(8)
registerDoParallel(cluster)

# left eye, right eye, mouth
data.train <- data.table(fread('Data/training.csv', 
                               header = TRUE, 
                               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)) %>%
  dplyr::select(left_eye_center_x, 
                left_eye_center_y, 
                right_eye_center_x, 
                right_eye_center_y, 
                mouth_center_top_lip_x, 
                mouth_center_top_lip_y, 
                Image)

images <- foreach(image = data.train$Image) %dopar% {
  as.integer(unlist(strsplit(image, " ")))
}

stopCluster(cluster)

data.train$img <- images
data.train$Image <- NULL

rm('images', 'cluster')

save(data.train, file = 'Data/cleaned.Rd')
```

and I'm trying to create the model itself like so...

```
# model.R

library(data.table)
library(neuralnet)
library(caret)

if (!exists('data.train')) {
  if (file.exists('Data/cleaned.Rd')) {
    load('Data/cleaned.Rd')
  } else {
    source('load.R')
  }
}

model.lex <- lm(left_eye_center_x~img, data = data.train)
```

The following, which I was experimenting with first, produces the same error

```
nn.grid <- expand.grid(.decay = c(0, 0.01, 0.1), 
                       .size = c(1:10), 
                       .bag = FALSE)

nn.left.eye.x <- train(left_eye_center_x ~ img, 
                       data = data.train, 
                       method = "neuralnet", 
                       tunegrid = nn.grid, 
                       maxit = 100, 
                       linout = TRUE, 
                       trace = FALSE)
```

No success trying to convert it to another type as well (ie. left_eye_center_x ~ as.data.frame(img)).

I'm a bit stumped.